# Export from Camtasia to Premiere Pro, with good audio

Tags: premiere

How can I export from Camtasia to Premiere Pro keeping the two audio tracks as separate audio tracks in Premiere Pro?

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, do two different exports, one with each audio track muted and then put them on separate tracks in Premiere.